# localhost:5012 Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I've started up a new server, running it on port 5012, and it's showing Connected to MongoDB. But when I try the port number like this localhost://5012 on my browser, it displays Cannot GET /[image]

Comment: Try  localhost:5012/api/items

Comment: what do you have on `/api/items`? show us the code from `server.js` and `items.js`. and please use text instead of an image.

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    // Create Schema
    const ItemSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
       },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
       }
});

    module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
This is for items.js

Comment: no, I mean the file that you have for router at `/api/items`

Comment: Okay, Please I'm sorry, I thought it was Item.js.

Comment: const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Items Model
const Item = require('../../models/Item');
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Item.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(items => res.json(items))
});

Answer (score 0):

Your app is running locally on port 5012.

You should be able to access http://localhost:5012/api/items but not just http://localhost:5012 because your express server doesn't have route handler for '/' route.